# Story about a man who wakes, then hibernates, for decades

Tags: story-identification

I read a short story or part if a novel about a man who doesn't sleep for years but then hibernates for decades. All I remember is he will find a cave to sleep in. And he never or slowly ages. It was late 80s, early 90s

Comment: Definitely a short story.  He ages very slowly, as in hundreds of times more slowly than normal.

Comment: @DavidW Thousands of times slower (if we're thinking of the same story). "I have aged eleven years in the past hundred and eighty millennia."

Comment: @user14111 It's definitely the same story; somewhere I have the Jan 1990 60th anniversary edition of *Analog*.  And 16000 times is 160 hundreds. :D

Answer (score 16):

["Letter to a Phoenix"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56135), a short story by [Fredric Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredric_Brown), first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, August 1949](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57413+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v43n06_1949-08_cape1736/page/n145/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56135), perhaps in the [60<sup>th</sup> anniversary edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56897+c) (January 1990) of *Analog* (née *Astounding*).

> The factors of decay and aging were not eliminated, of course, but the rate was reduced by about fifteen thousand times. I age at the rate of one day every forty-five years. So I am not immortal. I have aged eleven years in the past hundred and
> eighty millennia. My physical age is now thirty-four.
>
> And forty-five years is to me as a day. I do not sleep for about thirty years of it—then I sleep for about fifteen. It is well for me that my first few “days” were not spent in a period of complete social disorganization or savagery, else I would not
> have survived my first few sleeps. But I did survive them and by that time I had learned a system and could take care of my own survival. Since then, I have slept about four thousand times, and I have survived. Perhaps someday I shall be unlucky.
> Perhaps someday, despite certain safeguards, someone will discover and break into the cave or vault into which I seal myself, secretly, for a period of sleep. But it is not likely. I have years in which to prepare each of those places and the experience of four thousand sleeps back of me. You could pass such a place a thousand times and never know it was there, nor be able to enter if you suspected.